# XML schema error with Jetty

Tags: java, xml, xsd, spring-security, jetty

I got a problem with my spring configuration when I run it in jetty. I used the exact same file in tomcat without any problems. The error i get is the following.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 6 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/web-application-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'SpringSource.org | '.
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'SpringSource.org | '.
```

My schema looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.5.xsd">
```

I have no idea what can be wrong. Have tested it with 2 different configurations and both gave this error.

Comment: check from the XSDs listed there http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you can not have a newline character inside XML attribute.

Put `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute value all inside one line.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/a/449647/90033

Comment: @Konstantin: this is not the question of XML standards, but a problem that happens when this particular parser can not load an external schema.

Comment: I know but your answer seems to imply that he cant have newlines in xml attributes which is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

The following URL seems invalid, and redirects to springsource.org

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.5.xsd
```

Can you try that one?

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.4.xsd
```

Comment: Ah tnx. such simple solution. I expected an other error for invalid schema locations since I got such error before. Still got same error but now more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the spring security part that is messing this up look at [Spring 3.0 - Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161050/spring-3-0-unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace?rq=1) for a solution. (Short recap you are missing the Spring Security Config jar in your classpath add the below dependency if you are using maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```