# spring-security-web error loading context

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security

I am attempting to use [Web Security Expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-access-web) however when I load the context in my unit test I get `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed`

My context file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

 // various beans here

 <sec:http use-expressions="true">
   <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin*"
      access="hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')"/>
  </sec:http>

</beans>
```

If I don't include the `<sec:http>` tag I don't get the error. If I include just `<sec:http/>` I do get the error.

In my pom I have included:

```
<dependancy>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependancy>
```

Comment: Do you have any problems with http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd URL (in the environment where your test was executed)?

Comment: I get a 404 for it as well as all the other xsds I use. I assume it is getting the schemas from the jars at runtime? Not sure how to check if it can be found vs the others I use.

Comment: This one normally loaded via network. I do not have any problems with it (can view it in my web browser).

Comment: This seems to be a cousin to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161050/spring-3-0-unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTD files like this one

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
```

must be available for XML parser during each parse action. Make them available and the problem will go away.

Comment: So if we assume that my application does not have access to the internet, it must be getting the schema (including the other ones that it is OK with) from someplace. I would assume that it would be getting it from the jar included via the maven dependancy. Am I wrong here or do I not have the right dependancy?

Comment: You are right. spring-security-config.jar is the right dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the schemas for spring security are in the `spring-security-config` jar. I needed that dependancy.