# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j]

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to add spring data for neo4j to an existing project. I can't solve the following error.

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: 
Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-config.xml]

at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

My pom is rather big, but the neo4j and/or spring data dependencies are below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The app-confiv.xml contains the namespace definition and the bean instantiation:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-3.0.xsd
    ">

<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" base-package="my.example.package.model"/>
<neo4j:repositories base-package="my.example.package.repository"/>  

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.CypherRestGraphDatabase">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://localhost:7474/db/data" />
</bean>
```

Looking at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161050/spring-3-0-unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace?rq=1) it seems that there is a dependency missing that causes this error. However, I could not figure out which dependency is missing neither how to spot the missing one in the other cases.

Comment: There is no `spring-data-neo4j-tx` anymore in 3.3.2. I would just add `spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.3.2`

Comment: I have gotten past this error before seeing your comment by changing the spring data version from `3.3.2` to `3.3.1`. I now tried to remove the `spring-data-neo4j-tx` and I didn't get the error back even after upgrading to `3.3.2`. 

I'm not sure if it was the tx dependency or a maven/eclipse issue, thus +1 on your comment instead of asking to post it in a reply which I could accept.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the version here:

`http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-3.0.xsd`

that one was probably removed (outdated) you can either leave the version off or use `3.2` or perhaps `3.3`

Comment: I had already tried that. 2.0, 3.0, 3.2 or 3.3 neither made any change with respect to the error I get.