# Spring Hadoop - Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-hadoop

I want to enable Hive in my Spring Hadoop project.  I understand that we can't use JavaConfiguration so I am using XML.  I have an error regarding the Spring Namespace.

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. [2017-10-03
>   10:26:51.292] - 44342 SEVERE [main] ---
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for
>   XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop]
>
> Offending resource: class path resource [hiveContext.xml]

My pom has the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop-boot</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I know some other posts talks about SpringSecurity, but I don't have access to a **spring-hadoop-config** dependency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring 3.0 - Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace \[http://www.springframework.org/schema/security\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161050/spring-3-0-unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace)

Comment: The other post talks about spring-security.  I don't have a config dependency in spring hadoop.

Comment: There are a number of other same title questions on SO you can look at.

Comment: I've also tried the maven-shade-plugin plugin.

Comment: I had the same error and adding this dependency fixed it but I would think this would be included in the spring-data-hadoop-boot artifact.

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

you can try to add this one as well.